# Write $-\Delta u-(1-u^2-v^2)u=0$ and $-\Delta v-(1-u^2-v^2)v=0$ in terms of $w=u^2+v^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Considering the following system:
Let $\Omega=B_1(0)$
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u-(1-u^2-v^2)u=0\\
-\Delta v-(1-u^2-v^2)v=0\\
v|_\Omega=u|_\Omega=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Let $w:=u^2+v^2$, I am trying to show $|w|_{L^\infty(\bar{\Omega})}\leq1$.
To do this, I try to rewrite the system in terms of $w$.
Noticing $\frac{1}{2} \Delta w=u\Delta u+v\Delta v+ (\partial_i u)^2+(\partial_i v)^2$. By multiplying the first equation by $u$ and the second equation by $v$, We have $\frac{1}{2}\Delta w+(1-w)w=(\partial_i u)^2+(\partial_i v)^2$. But I got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suppose that $u,v$ are classical solutions, that is, $u,v\in C^2(B_1)\cap C(\overline{B_1})$. Then we also have that $w\in C^2(B_1)\cap C(\overline{B_1})$. As you have established, $$\frac 1 2 \Delta w+(1-w)w=\vert \nabla u \vert^2+ \vert \nabla v \vert^2\geqslant 0 \qquad \text{in }B_1 \tag{$\ast$}$$ (I assume you that you meant to sum over $i$). Moreover, $$w=0\qquad \text{on } \partial B_1.$$

Suppose that, for the sake of contradiction, $\max_{B_1}w >1$. Since $w$ is continuous, there exists $x_\star \in \overline{B_1}$ such that $w(x_\star)=\max_{B_1}w.$ In fact, since $w=0$ on $\partial B_1$, we must have $x_\star \in B_1$. Then, since $w$ attains its maximum at $x_\star$, we have that $\Delta w (x_\star )\leqslant 0$ and so  $$\frac 1 2 \Delta w(x_\star)+(1-w(x_\star))w(x_\star)\leqslant(1-w(x_\star))w(x_\star)<0  $$ since $w(x_\star)>1$. This contradicts ($\ast$). Thus, we have that $$0\leqslant w\leqslant 1 \qquad \text{in } \overline{B_1}. $$